# CV and/or resume for PhD Student with industry experience?

Tags: cv

I spent 10+ years in industry before going back to grad school to pursue a PhD, and therefore I have extensive industry experience, as well as ongoing academic work.
Is there a good way to represent this on my CV? Does anyone know a good CV format or template that would allow me to show this?

Comment: I have a section titled "Other Experience" for my non-academic work (both pre-PhD and after) that is substantively related to my field of study, but not actually academic work

Comment: what type of work did you do in industry? Was it R&D, production, sales & marketing? Also, what field is this?

Comment: @Burak the industry was marine engineering, specifically in operations. I also have a pre-grad school academic career, also in marine engineering.

Comment: It depends what you're applying for - for industry jobs, you probably want reverse-chronological order so the PhD would get top billing followed by the job, with some specifics related to the PhD later on.  For an academic CV the old job would be much less important and would probably fall off the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there are a couple ways to attack this. You could list academic experience as a separate section to industry experience, this would show that you consider them very separate.

You could also make a section titled " (Relevant) Experience" and list everything you have in chronological order. This would give the impression to whoever is reading it that you consider all of your experience relevant in the position that you are applying to.

In either case, make sure you highlight the relevant portions of your background to the position you are applying.

Comment: That's a useful suggestion, thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 1):

In a standard C.V., there is a section where you list all of the professional positions that you have held, typically newest to oldest.  You can simply include your industry work in that section.

If you feel that your work experience is particularly relevant to your aims in graduate school, I would recommend highlighting it strongly in other parts of your application outside of your C.V.  For example, you may discuss it in your research statement, one of your references may be one of your supervisors, etc.